# How to close ngx-bootstrap modal on router.navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap ModalService.
I have an interceptor that redirects the user to login page based on some condition  using router.navigate(['/login']) . Redirection works fine but the modal stays open.
I know I could implement OnDestroy and close it there, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do that on every component that displays a modal, seems repetitive. Is there a way to close a modal / all (possible) open modals at redirect time (doing it on the interceptor also feels I'm coupling stuff).
I apologize If I'm not asking the question the right way, this is my first time. If you need further details, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you could listen for router changes and close the model when a route changes

```
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    // close the router here
});
```

you can add this in the main component or add it in a service

Comment: sorry if I'm missing the point, but wouldn't that need to be included in every component?. How would the "aad it in a service" approach be like?. Thanks again.

Comment: You could add it as a service and initialize it in the starting component. So it will listen to all the router events until you unsubscribe it.